# How to determine SignTabs X and Y position

Tags: docusignapi

Prior to using the DocuSign api to create an envelope, how do I figure out the X and Y positions for placing SignTabs on my documents? The document I'm working with is a PDF so I tried the PDF coordinate system but that didn't work. Also tried adding the signature field manually using the DocuSign portal, but no coordinates are shown.

```
signer.Tabs = new Tabs();
signer.Tabs.SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>();
SignHere signHere = new SignHere();
signHere.DocumentId = "1";
signHere.PageNumber = "1";
signHere.RecipientId = "1";
signHere.XPosition = "100";
signHere.YPosition = "100";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have set the X and Y position using DS Web Portal then using API check the Envelope JSON to know the exact X and Y Position. Setting X and Y position is not an ideal solution as it will fluctuates on each system. If you own the PDF creation then you can use DocuSign's Anchor String functionality to place the DocuSign tabs. You can check more details at [Automatically add tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100353/automatically-add-tags)