# docusign api counter-signature sees multiple signing points

Tags: docusignapi

[MultipleSigningPointsExample

```js
{
    "emailBlurb": "Auto-generated by Outsystems Platform",
    "emailSubject": "Please approve attached document",
    "enableWetSign": "True",

    "notification":{
    "useAccountDefaults":"false",
    "reminders":{
      "reminderEnabled":"True",
      "reminderDelay":"1",
      "reminderFrequency":"3"
    },
    "expirations":{
      "expireEnabled":"True",
      "expireAfter":"15",
      "expireWarn":"1"
    }
  },

  "documents": [
    
    {
      "name": "Doc1.docx",
      "documentId":"286",
      "order":"1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Doc2.docx",
      "documentId":"287",
      "order":"2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Doc3.docx",
      "documentId":"285",
      "order":"3"
    }
],
    "recipients": {
    "signers": [

     
        {      
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "anchorString": "Please Sign Here:",
              "tabId": "1",
              "name": "Sign Here 0"
            }
            ],
             "textTabs": [
            {
              "anchorString": "Please Sign Here (Position):",
              "tabId": "1position",
              "name": "Position",
              "width": 50
            },
            {
              "anchorString": "Please Sign Here (Drawdown Date):",
              "tabId": "1drawdown",
              "name": "DrawDownDate",
              "width": 50,
              "tabLabel":"Drawdown date (dd/mm/yyyy)"
            },
            {
              "anchorString": "Please Sign Here (FullName):",
              "tabId": "1fullname",
              "name": "FullName",
              "width": 50,
              "tabLabel":"1FullName"
            }
           ]
        },
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "requireSignOnPaper" : "false",
        "recipientId": "437",
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "email": "*******"
      }, 
        {      
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "anchorString": "Please Sign Here 2:",
              "tabId": "2",
              "name": "Sign Here 1"
            }
            ],
             "textTabs": [
            {
              "anchorString": "Please Sign Here 2 (Position):",
              "tabId": "2position",
              "name": "Position",
              "width": 50,
              "tabLabel":"2Position"
            }
            ,
            {
              "anchorString": "Please Sign Here 2 (FullName):",
              "tabId": "2fullname",
              "name": "FullName",
              "width": 50,
              "tabLabel":"2FullName"
            }
           ]
        },
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "requireSignOnPaper" : "false",
        "recipientId": "438",
        "name": "Taylor Swift",
        "email": "*******"
      }, 
        {      
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "anchorString": "Please sign guarantee here:",
              "tabId": "3",
              "name": "Sign Here 2"
            }
            ],
             "textTabs": [
            {
              "anchorString": "Please sign guarantee here (Position):",
              "tabId": "3position",
              "name": "Position",
              "width": 50,
              "tabLabel":"3Position"
            }
            ,
            {
              "anchorString": "Please sign guarantee here (FullName):",
              "tabId": "3fullname",
              "name": "FullName",
              "width": 50,
              "tabLabel":"3FullName"
            }
           ]
        },
        "routingOrder": "3",
        "requireSignOnPaper" : "false",
        "recipientId": "440",
        "name": "Dua Lipa",
        "email": "*******"
      }, 
        {      
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "anchorString": "Please sign guarantee here 2:",
              "tabId": "4",
              "name": "Sign Here 3"
            }
            ],
             "textTabs": [
            {
              "anchorString": "Please sign guarantee here 2 (Position):",
              "tabId": "4position",
              "name": "Position",
              "width": 50,
              "tabLabel":"4Position"
            }
            ,
            {
              "anchorString": "Please sign guarantee here 2 (FullName):",
              "tabId": "4fullname",
              "name": "FullName",
              "width": 50,
              "tabLabel":"4FullName"
            }
           ]
        },
        "routingOrder": "3",
        "requireSignOnPaper" : "false",
        "recipientId": "441",
        "name": "Rita Ora",
        "email": "*******"
      }, 
        {      
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "anchorString": "ECBCounterSigner",
              "tabId": "5",
              "name": "Sign Here 4"
            }
            ],
             "textTabs": [
            {
              "anchorString": "ECBCounterSigner (Position):",
              "tabId": "5position",
              "name": "Position",
              "width": 50,
              "tabLabel":"5Position"
            }
            ,
            {
              "anchorString": "ECBCounterSigner (FullName):",
              "tabId": "5fullname",
              "name": "FullName",
              "width": 50,
              "tabLabel":"5FullName"
            }
           ]
        },
        "routingOrder": "4",
        "requireSignOnPaper" : "false",
        "recipientId": "439",
        "name": "Chief Finance Officer (CFO)",
        "email": "*******"
      }

    ]
  },
  
    "status": "sent"

  }
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K31oQ.png)We've configured a docusign signing flow that routes documents for an additional final signature after they're initially signed (counter-signature).

The envelope is correctly routed to the final signer and they correctly see 1 signing point & 2 text tabs to capture their Full Name and Position.  On top of these 2 text tabs they also are prompted for 2 additional signatures.  Is this intended behaviour as they're signing a document that's already been signed by another recipient.  The xml request we're making via the API doesn't specify these 2 additional signing points for the final recipient.

Comment: I think I have covered the three ways you can get "extra" tabs, so please update the question after you have had a chance to debug.

Comment: Can you share your XML request which you are sending for creating an envelope, its easy to troubleshoot with exact request?

Comment: Thanks guys, I've added an image illustrating the multiple signing points that the order 4 signer is being prompted with + the json request.  We're not using salesforce to generate the request.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect any one of these three issues for the "cloned/extra" tags for the second recipient:

1. Anchor String is found twice
2. A User Custom Tag with Anchor String that is shared is found also
3. Your sending from Salesforce and so the API and Salesforce tags are being applied aka \s1\

You can you capture exact JSON/SOAP request posted by your API calls by following steps explained at this DocuSign support article https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

You can find what User Custom Tags are being "applied" by reviewing the Custom Tabs defined by all the users in your by reviewing the admin guide as well as this link to get an idea of both the DocuSign and Salesforce defined and used tags

https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/dfs-user-guide/Content/user-guide/add-custom-tags-w-merge-field-settings-user.htm

https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-user-guide-use-automatic-anchor-text-with-custom-tags-user

https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/dfs-user-guide/Content/user-guide/create-merge-fields-user.htm#Creating2

Also here is a similar Stack Overflow Q&A [Automatically add tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100353/automatically-add-tags)

Please update the question/resolution once you determine which it was and how you found it. Also, would be great if you can update the question with actual Json/SOAP you capture, Image of Document you sent and the resulting image of duplicate tabs (aka TAGS, SECURED TAB, CUSTOM TAB, MERGE FIELDS, ... marketing term of the day - us dev's know them as TABs per the schema)